# Can't install DiffMerge. Error showing "dependency is not satisfiable :libcurl3(>=7.16.2-1)"

Tags: apt, software-installation, java, dependencies, gdebi

I was trying to install DiffMerge. I downloaded the `.deb` package from the SourceGear website. But while installing it, it shows the following error

> dependency is not satisfiable :libcurl3(>=7.16.2-1)

Can anyone please help me in solving this issue?
As I am studying Java, I need DiffMerge as it helps to compare the codes.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? That is a very old version of libcurl, and all currently supported versions have a newer libcurl available. Though versions newer than 18.04 may no longer have libcurl3 as the ABI changed, so the package you're trying to install would need to be rebuilt against a newer curl.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 19.04, disco dingo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On modern 19.04 system you will not able to satisfy the dependencies of the software from 2013 year. But you may try with 16.04 LTS.

Instead I would suggest to install similar packages from the repository on any Ubuntu version - one of:

- [MeldMerge](http://meldmerge.org/) with `sudo apt install meld`
- [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) with `sudo apt install kdiff3`

Comment: Thank you so much. Helped me a lot.